# Favorite Questions and Answers from first quarter of 2016

Tags: discussion, blog

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from January 1st 2016 through March 31 2016 (**They don't have to be *your* questions and answers.**).

La la la la la la, la la la la la. Will the Smurf theme be enough to trick StackExchange? We'll have to wait and see.

Your answers will be compiled into a blog post like previous [quarterly posts](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/category/qotw/).

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2016/01/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2016/01/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2016/01/01)

**This has now gone live. http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/04/highlights-from-2016-1st-quarter/**

Comment: Does my deleted answer still count?

Comment: @ibid Yes, I included CHEESE's response, even though your answer was deleted.

Answer (score 7):

## Favourite questions

In no particular order:

- **randal'thor's** question **[When did pure-historical *Doctor Who* go out of fashion?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114773/when-did-pure-historical-doctor-who-go-out-of-fashion)** — I like questions that track trends in long-running science fiction works!
- **N_Soong's** question **[Are any regular bridge crew on *TNG* actually members of the next generation?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122654/are-any-regular-bridge-crew-on-tng-actually-members-of-the-next-generation)** — One of those questions that few would think about until an astute observer asks it!
- **WadCheber's** question **[Which is bigger: the Star Forge or the Death Star?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116040/which-is-bigger-the-star-forge-or-the-death-star)** — I'm partial to this one for several reasons: it's an interesting question that tries to put two mega-structures in the *Star Wars* universe on some common ground, but I also like it because I answered it and enjoyed doing the calculations that resolved the question (and I netted a 500-point bounty in the process — thanks Wad!)

## Favourite answers

Also in no particular order:

- **Richard's** answer to **[Was Kylo Ren's lightsaber activated by the character that it then killed?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122275/was-kylo-rens-lightsaber-activated-by-the-character-that-it-then-killed)** — I always enjoy an answer that locks down a question completely, with multiple references that leave no room for quibbling...
- **DVK's** answer to **[What does an astromech droid actually do while deployed in combat?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/114250/40294)** — a comprehensive, model answer!
- **Mazura's** amazing answer to **[Where is Vader's meditation chamber on the Executor?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/116904/40294)** — such excellent work deserves more votes!
- **Politank-Z's** answer to **[Which Clark Gable movie did Edith Keeler want to see with Captain Kirk?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/116331/40294)** — while not the accepted answer, it's an enjoyable example of lateral thinking

Comment: Only one Star Trek question in these nominations? Shame on you! :-P

Comment: @randal'thor : I know, it's like I've forgotten who I am!  ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor : I've added another, so it's all good now.  :-)

Answer (score 5):

**Best questions**

[How much was accomplished with the practical BB-8 prop?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/113380/4918) (Keen's question) - I like this one because I'd heard contradictory rumors before, like that no moving props were used and the BB-8 in the desert was all computer animated.

[Why are storm troopers legs asymmetrical?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/118212/4918) (Jonathan.'s question)

[What is the "About the Author" blurb in Shadows of the Empire supposed to say?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/118387/4918) (Wad Cheber's question)

**Best answers**

[What's the story behind the Spock helmet?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/117108/4918) (Jason Baker's answer)

[What other Harry Potter related writings has Rowling written?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/114611/4918) (ibid's answer) - a great list of references.

**Questions of unusual topics**

[Pears in Doctor Who](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/114090/4918) (Rand al'Thor's question)

[Which 'finger' was BB-8 sticking up?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/115402/4918)  (Keen's question)

Comment: You made it in time, since the blog post won't go out until tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

## Favourite Question

**[What is the in-universe title of Yandel's ‘A World of Ice and Fire’?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116115/what-is-the-in-universe-title-of-yandels-a-world-of-ice-and-fire)**

For attracting [yet another professional to our site](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8074/21267).

## Favourite Answer

My own [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/117943/21267) to **[How many people actually died during The War of the Five Kings?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/107687/how-many-people-actually-died-during-the-war-of-the-five-kings)** because any excuse for me to dig deep into the ASOIAF lore is a joy for me.

Answer (score 3):

### Favourite question

I liked this one because, quite frankly, I had the same question in mind while I was watching the film

- **[If Luke Skywalker didn’t want to be found, why did he leave a map?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113497/if-luke-skywalker-didn-t-want-to-be-found-why-did-he-leave-a-map)**

### Favourite Answer

Not to blow my own trumpet, but I thought my own answer to this question was nicely comprehensive

- **[Was Kylo Ren's lightsaber activated by the character that it then killed?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122275/was-kylo-rens-lightsaber-activated-by-the-character-that-it-then-killed)**

as was my answer to this one

- **[Why did the Dursleys give Harry glasses?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120122/why-did-the-dursleys-give-harry-glasses)**

Comment: The lens flare from your modesty is blinding me.

Answer (score 2):

As a start, my favorite answer to one of my questions this quarter was https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/117720/51142

Comment: Apparently other people didn't share your enthusiasm.